# Turing machine remembering its position

Tags: turing-machines

I want to built a TM, which can remember its position $n$, jump to the beginning of the tape and then iterate to the right until it's on the position $n-1$ (I can't use step to the left). I don't know how to achieve this position remembering and then comparing it to the current position. Is it somehow possible to achieve this behaviour with a TM?

Comment: How many tapes does your TM have?

Comment: @AlexVong Just one.

Comment: can you replace the alphabet $A$ with a different alphabet $A\times\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: The point to do anything you'd want is really to build an universal TM $u$. Do you see how running a TM yields a sequence of states (or integers) $a_n$ ? Then the transformation law $a_{n+1} = TM(a_n)$ can be simulated in $u$.